# Making the sub folders to subdomain form in apache linux

Tags: php, linux, apache

I am creating sub folders on my domain in this format:

`http://example.com/f1`.

I'm creating the folders like this. I want to access their contents with the url in this format:

`http://f1.example.com` not in `http://example.com/f1.`

I am using apache linux OS with php as server language.
Please help with this. How can I do this?

Comment: The apache http server supports "virtual hosts" which is what you are looking for. I suggest you start reading the documentation...

Comment: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts/

Comment: do u mean httpd.conf file.Please can you guide with an example for my case that how virtual hosts should be modified.

Comment: What _exactly_ is it that you do not understand in the documentation I linked? It is well written, precise, complete and even offers a section "Virtual Host examples for common setups"...

Comment: the link came after i posted reply to ur answer.

Comment: I added an answer below to make things easier.

Answer (score 0):

If your hosting provider supports cPanel you can easily create sub domains. Go to your hosting cPanel. Find the option named "Sub Domains". In there, you will be able to create sub domains under your domain.

Comment: True. But at present, most of the hosting provider supports cPanel or similar user interface to control everything. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: And how come you assume the OP uses a hosted space?

Comment: This is the most common case. If it's something else, he can say that.

Answer (score 0):

The apache http server offer the "virtual hosts" feature for exactly this purpose. The feature offers a very good documentation as typical for apache projects:
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/en/vhosts

That documentation also offers a convenient section "Virtual Host examples for common setups". In there you can see a perfect example for your setup:

Basically you define one "virtual host" per such folder:

```
Listen 80
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/hosts/f1"
    ServerName f1.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/hosts/f2"
    ServerName f2.example.com

    # Other directives here
</VirtualHost>
```

This obviously requires that you have control over the http server, so access to the configuration. If that is *not* the case, for example because you do *not* operate the system yourself but use some cheap shared hosting provider, then you should consult their documentation how to achieve this. They might offer some tool for the purpose which grants you limited access to the above feature.

With that setup you can now make requests to the two separate hosts:

- http://f1.example.com
- http://f2.example.com

Note that for this to work you additionally have to take care of the domain name resolution. The host names must be resolved to IP addresses, there is no way around that if you want to use different host names. The distinction which host is requested if both host names ("subdomains") resolve to the same IP address is done via the `HOST` header in the http request. This also means that requests to the raw IP address will be served by the default host which is the first host defined in the above setup.

Comment: thanks man.how can we add a wildacrd entry here in virtual host so that all folders inside that should show in this way. http://www.xyz.example.com

Comment: Two options for this: 1. you use a "default host" in the setup above which serves all requests to hosts that are _not_ explicitly defined and then switch between folders by means of a central router script that evaluates the `HOST` header in the http request, or 2. you use so called "mass virtual hosting" which allows to keep specific host definitions in a database, thus offering much more flexibility. Both approaches are well documented too.

Comment: i used above snippet but now its showing f1.example.com content when i go to example.com.

Comment: Isn't that what you would expect when thinking about the concept of a "default host" and the host `example.com` _not_ explicitly being defined?